# Can I travel to New Zealand with an expired H4 visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, new-zealand, passport-renewals, h1b-visas

I am planning to go to New Zealand with my husband. I have an H4 (dependent visa) which is up for renewal. I am planning to go to New Zealand, spend 10 days and go to India, renew my visa and come back to the USA. Will there be problems while applying for a NZ visa?

Answer (score 2):

Your US H4 visa status will have no effect whatsoever on whether or not you are successful in obtaining a visa for New Zealand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I have a huge travel plan associated with this, it would be great if I could get this officially confirmed. Is there a website/link which officially says the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vaishnavi: You will not find an official site that specifically says "H4 status doesn't matter". The reason is that US visa status is not something the New Zealand visitor visa rules talk about at all. The best I can point you to is the [Visa Conditions](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa#https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/visa-factsheet/conditions/visitor-visa) for the visitor visa. When you fill out the application, you should find that nowhere does it ask anything about foreign visa status.